# Why do images that have EXIF metadata stripped still appear when using Google Image Search?

Tags: google-search

I have stripped images that we own of any metadata however they still appear when using Google Image Search. Why is that?

Comment: Are you searching using an image?

Comment: @ChrisN - Yes I am. They are private photos but it seems that Google has indexed them somehow.

Comment: Then stripping the metadata won't help if you are looking for matching images.

Comment: Did you strip the metadata *after* Google had "somehow" indexed them?

Comment: @Karan - Yes. Is there a way I can alter them so that if someone does upload them using Google's image search, it'll be harder to locate.

Comment: @ChrisN - What are my options?

Comment: You could try [this](http://support.google.com/images/answer/181721/?hl=en)

Comment: @ChrisN - Thanks. I already had a look at that but want to stop reverse image search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `robots.txt` to block access to those images and wait for `googlebot` to revisit your site. After the visit remove the `robots.txt rules` and rename the files and the next time `googlebot` revists it will index the new images (stripped of metadata).

Warning: you might have image downtime on google

Comment: Thanks. I already had a look at that but want to stop reverse image search.

Comment: you'll need a robots.txt file combined with a Complete removal from Google's Webmasters Tools as @ChrisN suggested